# Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'DTLSv1_METHOD'

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import sys, os, select, socket

cudp = SSL.Context(SSL.DTLSv1_METHOD)
```

Error:

```
Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'DTLSv1_METHOD'
```

Python 2.7.6

OpenSSL 1.1.0e

Comment: Why did you think `SSL.DTLSv1_METHOD` was a thing?

Comment: @user2357112 https://gist.github.com/manuels/8852953

Comment: It doesn't look like that code actually works. The first comment is some guy saying they're pretty sure it doesn't work. No such thing appears in the [docs](http://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/ssl.html) or in [pyopenssl's GitHub repository](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DTLSv1_METHOD).

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, do you know any python implementation for securing udp connection.. i cant find any?

Comment: On that topic, I only know as much as the [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+dtls) provide.

Comment: Did you compile Python with OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1.0? Or is this a distro's version of Python? he reason I ask is no distros provide 1.1.0 that I am aware. Python is likely expecting 1.0.2 or 1.0.1.

Answer (score -1):

> `Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'DTLSv1_METHOD'`

I'm not sure what Python is providing, but let me show you what OpenSSL is doing. From below, maybe you can try `DTLS_method`, `DTLS_server_method` or `DTLS_client_method`.

OpenSSL's GitHub:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
$ cd openssl
```

OpenSSL 1.1.0 (tip of Master):

```
$ git checkout master -f
$ grep -IR DTLS * | grep METHOD | grep ssl.h
...
include/openssl/ssl.h:# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DTLS1_METHOD
include/openssl/ssl.h:# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DTLS1_METHOD
include/openssl/ssl.h:DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.0 */
include/openssl/ssl.h:DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_server_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.0 */
include/openssl/ssl.h:DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_client_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.0 */
include/openssl/ssl.h:# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DTLS1_2_METHOD
include/openssl/ssl.h:DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_2_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.2 */
include/openssl/ssl.h:DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_2_server_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.2 */
include/openssl/ssl.h:DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_2_client_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.2 */
include/openssl/ssl.h:__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLS_method(void); /* DTLS 1.0 and 1.2 */
include/openssl/ssl.h:__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLS_server_method(void); /* DTLS 1.0 and 1.2 */
include/openssl/ssl.h:__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLS_client_method(void); /* DTLS 1.0 and 1.2 */
```

And OpenSSL 1.0.2:

```
$ git checkout OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable
$ grep -IR DTLS * | grep METHOD | grep ssl.h
ssl/ssl.h:const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_method(void); /* DTLSv1.0 */
ssl/ssl.h:const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_server_method(void); /* DTLSv1.0 */
ssl/ssl.h:const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_client_method(void); /* DTLSv1.0 */
ssl/ssl.h:const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_2_method(void); /* DTLSv1.2 */
ssl/ssl.h:const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_2_server_method(void); /* DTLSv1.2 */
ssl/ssl.h:const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_2_client_method(void); /* DTLSv1.2 */
ssl/ssl.h:const SSL_METHOD *DTLS_method(void); /* DTLS 1.0 and 1.2 */
ssl/ssl.h:const SSL_METHOD *DTLS_server_method(void); /* DTLS 1.0 and 1.2 */
ssl/ssl.h:const SSL_METHOD *DTLS_client_method(void); /* DTLS 1.0 and 1.2 */
```

You can find the OpenSSL man pages at [docs/manpages.html](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manpages.html).

Comment: hi .. no still not work i tried DTLS_method, DTLS_server_method or DTLS_client_method still the same